# Is there a functionality like the onFirstFix method in the Android Maps Api V2?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I can enable a myLocation View in the new Maps Api through [setMyLocationEnabled](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setMyLocationEnabled%28boolean%29).

The first version of the Api had a Method [runOnFirstFix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/) that enabled me to animate the map to the users location once the location is found. I can not find a listener or location like that in the Api Version 2.

Is there a solution to execute an action once the user is located?

Comment: Hey Janusz - was there an issue with my answer?  If so let me know and I'll update it, otherwise please accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Maps Android API V2 has a LocationSource.  From the docs:

"A GoogleMap object has a built-in location provider for its my-location layer, but it can be replaced with another one that implements this interface."

[LocationSource](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/LocationSource)

I imagine you'll need to use that in conjunction with a [LocationSource.OnLocationChangedListener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/LocationSource.OnLocationChangedListener)

**Update**

Figured it out.  If you want to do something similar to runOnFirstFix, here's a basic example that waits until the User's location is available, then animates the map to center on their location.

```
public class MyLocationMapFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener, LocationSource
{
/**
 * Note that this may be null if the Google Play services APK is not available.
 */
private GoogleMap mMap;

private OnLocationChangedListener mListener;
private LocationManager locationManager;

private Context mContext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.basic_map);

    this.mContext = this;

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //You may want to pass a different provider in as the first arg here
    //depending on the location accuracy that you desire
    //see LocationManager.getBestProvider()
    Criteria locationCriteria = new Criteria();
    locationCriteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.getBestProvider(locationCriteria, true), 1L, 2F, this);

    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    if(locationManager != null)
    {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    if(locationManager != null)
    {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}


/**
 * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
 * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
 * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
 * <p>
 * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
 * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
 * MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to install/update the Google Play services APK on
 * their device.
 * <p>
 * A user can return to this Activity after following the prompt and correctly
 * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the Activity may not have been
 * completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be stopped or
 * paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this method in
 * {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
 */
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) 
    {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.basicMap)).getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.

        //This is how you register the LocationSource
        mMap.setLocationSource(this);

        if (mMap != null) 
        {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
 * just add a marker near Africa.
 * <p>
 * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
 */
private void setUpMap() 
{
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public void activate(OnLocationChangedListener listener) 
{
    mListener = listener;
}

@Override
public void deactivate() 
{
    mListener = null;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{
    if( mListener != null )
    {
        mListener.onLocationChanged( location );

        //Move the camera to the user's location once it's available!
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())));
    }
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "provider disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "provider enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "status changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

**Update 2**

If you're interested in centering the map on the user's location when their location goes off screen (like MyLocationOverlay does in the old API), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13753518/1103584)

or this blog post: [Google Maps Android API V2 MyLocation LocationSource and event handling](http://discgolfsoftware.wordpress.com/2012/12/06/google-maps-android-api-v2-mylocation-locationsource-and-event-handling/)