# Map view following user - MyLocationOverlay type functionality for Android Maps API v2

Tags: android, api, maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I switched to v2 of Maps for Android, and I am trying to port over the following functionality:

With MyLocationOverlay I can show the devices current location (Blue Dot). When the user's location changes and the dot reaches the edge of the visible area, the map animates out so the dot becomes the center of the view, in real time.

In v2, I am using SupportMapFragment with getMap().setMyLocationEnabled(true). The current location appears as a blue dot(arrow), but when the device changes location, the map view does not shift and the dot eventually leaves the view.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Google introduced the new [`LocationClient`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html) and associated [`LocationListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener.html) (the `OnMyLocationChangeListener` interface is now deprecated). So now automatic centering of the camera is a trivial task.

---

Although spotdog already answered the question I wanted to share my own example, which I hope will help fellow Android beginners better understand what it takes to make a custom `LocationSource` for the my-location layer. Hopefully you will find that the code is well documented/commented.

```
public class PlaceMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {

    // Note that this may be null if the Google Play services APK is not available.
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    protected PlaceActivity activity;
    private FollowMeLocationSource followMeLocationSource;
    private Context mContext;

    /* We need the Context in order to get a reference to the Location Manager
     * (when instantiating this fragment from your activity use:
     *  PlaceMapFragment mapFragment = new PlaceMapFragment(this); ) */
    public PlaceMapFragment(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        activity = (PlaceActivity)getActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // creates our custom LocationSource and initializes some of its members
        followMeLocationSource = new FollowMeLocationSource();

        /* We can't be guaranteed that the map is available because Google Play services might not be available.
         * (un-comment the following line when using this code in a FragmentActivity / Activity 
         *  to try get a reference to the map here !) */
        //setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        /* We query for the best Location Provider everytime this fragment is displayed
         * just in case a better provider might have become available since we last displayed it */
        followMeLocationSource.getBestAvailableProvider();

        // Get a reference to the map/GoogleMap object
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        /* Enable the my-location layer (this causes our LocationSource to be automatically activated.)
         * While enabled, the my-location layer continuously draws an indication of a user's
         * current location and bearing, and displays UI controls that allow a user to interact
         * with their location (for example, to enable or disable camera tracking of their location and bearing).*/
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        /* Disable the my-location layer (this causes our LocationSource to be automatically deactivated.) */
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);

        super.onPause();
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
     * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated. This will ensure that we only ever
     * manipulate the map once when it {@link #mMap} is not null.
     * <p>
     * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
     * MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
     */
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            mMap = getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                // The Map is verified. It is now safe to manipulate the map:

                // Replace the (default) location source of the my-location layer with our custom LocationSource
                mMap.setLocationSource(followMeLocationSource);

                // Set default zoom
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15f));
            }
        }
    }

    /* Our custom LocationSource. 
     * We register this class to receive location updates from the Location Manager
     * and for that reason we need to also implement the LocationListener interface. */
    private class FollowMeLocationSource implements LocationSource, LocationListener {

        private OnLocationChangedListener mListener;
        private LocationManager locationManager;
        private final Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        private String bestAvailableProvider;
        /* Updates are restricted to one every 10 seconds, and only when
         * movement of more than 10 meters has been detected.*/
        private final int minTime = 10000;     // minimum time interval between location updates, in milliseconds
        private final int minDistance = 10;    // minimum distance between location updates, in meters

        private FollowMeLocationSource() {
            // Get reference to Location Manager
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Specify Location Provider criteria
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
            criteria.setAltitudeRequired(true);
            criteria.setBearingRequired(true);
            criteria.setSpeedRequired(true);
            criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        }

        private void getBestAvailableProvider() {
            /* The preffered way of specifying the location provider (e.g. GPS, NETWORK) to use 
             * is to ask the Location Manager for the one that best satisfies our criteria.
             * By passing the 'true' boolean we ask for the best available (enabled) provider. */
            bestAvailableProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        }

        /* Activates this provider. This provider will notify the supplied listener
         * periodically, until you call deactivate().
         * This method is automatically invoked by enabling my-location layer. */
        @Override
        public void activate(OnLocationChangedListener listener) {
            // We need to keep a reference to my-location layer's listener so we can push forward
            // location updates to it when we receive them from Location Manager.
            mListener = listener;

            // Request location updates from Location Manager
            if (bestAvailableProvider != null) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestAvailableProvider, minTime, minDistance, this);
            } else {
                // (Display a message/dialog) No Location Providers currently available.
            }
        }

        /* Deactivates this provider.
         * This method is automatically invoked by disabling my-location layer. */
        @Override
        public void deactivate() {
            // Remove location updates from Location Manager
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);

            mListener = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            /* Push location updates to the registered listener..
             * (this ensures that my-location layer will set the blue dot at the new/received location) */
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onLocationChanged(location);
            }

            /* ..and Animate camera to center on that location !
             * (the reason for we created this custom Location Source !) */
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Nevermore, thanks for your answer.  One thing I would like to mention is that I did initially have code to pick the "best available provider" for my LocationManager.  However, I was getting a lot of error reports from users and eventually determined that the getBestProvider method just plain doesn't work on some Android devices, so I removed it from my answer.

Comment: I think you really do not need to put context through constructor, because inside fragment you can get context by calling getActivity().getApplicationContext()

Comment: @shmoula If I remember correctly, using `activity.getApplicationContext()` didn't work for me in this case. I reckon it resulted in a runtime(?) error being thrown. I used that method successfully however in another fragment of same activity.

Answer (score 24):

You need to add a LocationSource to your GoogleMap and respond to onLocationChanged events.  Here is a simple class that asks for the user's location, then waits until the user's location is available and animates the map to center on their location.

```
public class MyLocationMapFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener, LocationSource
{
/**
 * Note that this may be null if the Google Play services APK is not available.
 */
private GoogleMap mMap;

private OnLocationChangedListener mListener;
private LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.basic_map);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if(locationManager != null)
    {
        boolean gpsIsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        boolean networkIsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if(gpsIsEnabled)
        {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000L, 10F, this);
        }
        else if(networkIsEnabled)
        {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000L, 10F, this);
        }
        else
        {
            //Show an error dialog that GPS is disabled.
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Show a generic error dialog since LocationManager is null for some reason
    }

    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    if(locationManager != null)
    {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    if(locationManager != null)
    {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}


/**
 * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
 * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
 * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
 * <p>
 * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
 * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
 * MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to install/update the Google Play services APK on
 * their device.
 * <p>
 * A user can return to this Activity after following the prompt and correctly
 * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the Activity may not have been
 * completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be stopped or
 * paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this method in
 * {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
 */
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) 
    {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.basicMap)).getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.

        if (mMap != null) 
        {
            setUpMap();
        }

        //This is how you register the LocationSource
        mMap.setLocationSource(this);
    }
}

/**
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
 * just add a marker near Africa.
 * <p>
 * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
 */
private void setUpMap() 
{
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public void activate(OnLocationChangedListener listener) 
{
    mListener = listener;
}

@Override
public void deactivate() 
{
    mListener = null;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{
    if( mListener != null )
    {
        mListener.onLocationChanged( location );

        //Move the camera to the user's location once it's available!
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())));
    }
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "provider disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "provider enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "status changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

This should follow the user and keep centering the map on their location as it changes - if you'd like to only center the map on the user when they go "off screen", then you could check to see if the user's location is within the visible bounds of the map

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{
    if( mListener != null )
    {
        mListener.onLocationChanged( location );

        LatLngBounds bounds = this.mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;

        if(!bounds.contains(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())))
        {
             //Move the camera to the user's location if they are off-screen!
             mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())));
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a short write up on the topic:
[Google Maps Android API V2 MyLocation LocationSource and event handling](http://discgolfsoftware.wordpress.com/2012/12/06/google-maps-android-api-v2-mylocation-locationsource-and-event-handling/)

**UPDATE**

I edited how I'm obtaining the user's location (see locationManager code in onCreate).  I've found that using the "getBestProvider" methods are not reliable and just plain don't work on several devices.  I had several users complain that their devices would never find their location, no matter how relaxed I made the criteria.  It seems that manually picking GPS or Network works universally.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. It also worked great in a class that extended SupportMapFragment (rather then FragmentActivity) implementing LocationListener, LocationSource.

Comment: Glad it works for you.  In my own App I'm actually extending SherlockFragmentActivity with this code because I'm using ActionBarSherlock, and that works great as well.

Comment: @DiscDev what about removing the default `blue dot on the map` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `OnMyLocationChangeListener`, override the method `public void onMyLocationChange(Location location)`. Use `GoogleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(your listener)` to register your listener.

```
public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
        changeMapLocation(location);
    }

    private void changeMapLocation(Location location) {
        LatLng latlong = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                location.getLongitude());
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlong, 15));

        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
    }
```