# Android: How can i animateTo my current location

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gps, location

How can i make my app to animate to my current Location? Part of my code look like this:

```
compass.enableMyLocation();
                lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 20000, 0, this);
```

I know, i have to use the use the animateTo method. But how can i combine my current location code and animateTo?

```
controller.animateTo(???);
          controller.setZoom(16);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Google Maps Android API v1, which is now [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/). That API has a built-in overlay, namely `MyLocationOverlay`, specifically for this kind of scenario.

I suggest, however, upgrading your app to using [Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/). This API doesn't have ready (built-in) functionality for this scenario, but it can be achieved with a few lines of code, as demonstrated by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13753518/1103584).