# Android GoogleMap stops reacting after pause-resume

Tags: android, fragment, google-maps-android-api-2

I am developing an app for tracking GPS data, that has a big GoogleMap in the interface showing what is being tracked. Things work the way I want just right until the activity pauses for whatever reason (phonecall, home-button etc) and I then resume the activity.

After the initial boot, the map doesn't react to any user interaction, and this works for me so far. Any call to animate the camera to a position works, markers are drawn and so is the user location and bearing.
After a pause-resume cycle it is the exact opposite. The map takes all gestures from the user, but doesn't react to any calls. I can't animate the camera, draw markers or show user location.

I tried a lot of things, trying to force a reload of the map setup in on resume and null'ing the map in pause, but nothing seems to work.

This is where I set up the map, called in onCreate (and tried in onResume):

```
private void setupMap(){
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.trackeractivity_map, new SupportMapFragment()).commit();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.trackeractivity_map);
    mMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}
```

This is where is where I update the user location and animate the camera:

```
private void updateUserLocation(double lat, double lon){
    Log.d(TAG, "updateUserLocation - " + lat + " : " + lon);
    mLastLocationLat = lat;
    mLastLocationLon = lon;
    if (mMap != null){
        CameraPosition userPos = new CameraPosition(new LatLng(lat, lon), mMap.getMaxZoomLevel()-4, 0, 0);
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(userPos));
    }
}
```

And this is where I add new markers to the track:

```
private void updateMapOverlay(double lat, double lon){
    Log.d(TAG, "updateMapOverlay - " + lat + " : " + lon + " - Type " + mCurrentType);
    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions();
    marker.position(new LatLng(lat, lon));
    marker.draggable(false);
    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(getTypeDrawableID(mCurrentType)));
    mMap.addMarker(marker);
}
```

And the map fragment in the layout:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/trackeractivity_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    />
```

As you can see I am using the supportfragmentmanager, and the activity also uses the SlidingMenu from JFeinstein - which works great BTW.

Any help on getting the map to work, even after a pause-resume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some possible issues with how you are adding the fragments in your setupMap method.  I suggest re-reading the guides from google, or checking out the following post, notably the blog post linked in the answer as it has a complete working class that can track the user's location and works fine with pause/resume.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13753518/1103584

Comment: Could you be more specific with the issues?

I'll take a look at your link and go through everything as well. Thanks..

Comment: For one, I don't think you should be adding the fragment in setupMap() (getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.trackeractivity_map, new SupportMapFragment()).commit();).  If you have the fragment defined in xml, you should just be able to call setContentView in the onCreate() method.  See this part of the developer's guide:  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#add_a_map

Comment: Lol and lol... I never spotted that part. I do have it in the layout and load it with setContent. It seems that removing that replace of the fragment fixed everything.