# Google Maps Android API v2 and current location

Tags: android, maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using JellyBean 4.2 and testing on my device.

How to get current location on clicking myLocationButton.

getMYLocation is returning null on using Network Provider.

I am using LocationManager to get current location and referring to Google documentation 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start.

After this clicking on MyLocatiionButton is not bringing any change

Comment: are using at device or emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically what you should do is make a call to Google Directions API receive the road direction coordinates (many Latlng points), and then draw a polyline between each one of them.

U can user either overview_polyline or legs and steps.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a LocationSource to your map fragment.  Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13753518/1103584) for a discrete example.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have all permission set in the Manifest?
Also, you have to enable the location service (is the gps icon in the status bar showing?). 
It'll take some time for the device to get the location, so see if onLocationChanged is called.

Comment: I have set all permissions as specified in documentation and gps icon also appears at status bar

Answer (score 1):

Use this code Id it does work.

```
private LocationManager locationManager;
private Location location;
private boolean hasGpsProvider, hasNetwrokProvider;

    public Location getLocation(Context mContext) {

        if (locationManager == null) {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }

        hasGpsProvider = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        hasNetwrokProvider = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (hasGpsProvider) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 100, locationListenerGps);
            location = locationManager
                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            return location;
        }

        if (hasNetwrokProvider) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 100,
                    locationListenerNetwork);
            location = locationManager
                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            return location;
        }

        return location;
    }
```

And call

```
if (location != null) {
    lat = location.getLatitude();
    lng = location.getLongitude();
}
```

Comment: will make changes later and inform you