# My-Location Button of GoogleMaps v2 Android, not displayed

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm doing an app, with google maps, but when I try to add "my-location" button, as the reference says doesn't work...

thats how I do:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        locManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        providersList = locManager.getAllProviders();
        provider =locManager.getProvider(providersList.get(0));
        precision = provider.getAccuracy();
        req = new Criteria();
        req.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);        
        inside = false;

        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

        buildPolygon();
        drawPolygon();
        startLocalization();
    }
```

I used `map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);` as shows in the reference of google. I don't know what's going on..

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The `myLocationButtonEnabled` is true by default and shown when the `setMyLocationEnabled` layer is enabled.

try this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    // Add this line
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    locManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    providersList = locManager.getAllProviders();
    provider =locManager.getProvider(providersList.get(0));
    precision = provider.getAccuracy();
    req = new Criteria();
    req.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);        
    inside = false;

    //map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

    buildPolygon();
    drawPolygon();
    startLocalization();
}
```

---

`setMyLocationEnabled` [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setMyLocationEnabled%28boolean%29)
`setMyLocationButtonEnabled` [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings#setMyLocationButtonEnabled%28boolean%29)

Comment: REallly!!! Oh god.. facepalm! 

Lot of thanks... it works perfect know. 

Didn't see this MyLocationEnale. Again, Thanks!!!

Comment: Happens to the best of us from time to time :). Glad I could help. Best of luck!

Comment: In my case, adding setMyLocationEnabled(true) does not help, unless at the same time location is fetched / listened to by my code. Somehow this triggers the blue dot to appear on the map.

Answer (score 3):

just add `map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` after create your map

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

to be like this

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line.

Kotlin:

```
map.isMyLocationEnabled = true
```

`map` is a GoogleMap object.

(More detailed answer(s) in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15142091/11211963 )

Answer (score 0):

For me, **map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);** 
It worked fine for below marshmallow devices and above marshmallow devices, I gave Location permission manually in-app settings.
Later My Location Button got visible.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers didn't work.

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap?) {
    this.googleMap = googleMap

    setupMap()
}

private fun setupMap() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context!!,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Before enabling the My Location layer, you must request location permission from the user.
        googleMap?.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        // *** Use this method ***
        googleMap?.uiSettings?.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = true

        // See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/location
        googleMap?.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this)
        googleMap?.setOnMyLocationClickListener(this)
    } else {
        // Show rationale and request permission.
        requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
            LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need **permission** to make it **visible**

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Maps_Activity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Maps_Activity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

   requestPermission();

   return;
}

mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```