# Map doesnt show current location

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to display current location in my app but it doesnt work .
Problem here is that it doesnt asign new value to currentLocation .

It display error that current Location is not initialized which I understand so i used to initalize it on in create by  Location("") which assigned to 0,0 but i still cannot assign to current place.

Here code :

```
private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
private lateinit var currentLocation : Location
private lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
private val REQUEST_CODE=101


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    fusedLocationProviderClient= LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(applicationContext as Context)
    fetchLastLocation()

    map_location_btn.setOnClickListener {
        onCartClicked()
    }
}

private fun fetchLastLocation() {
   if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), REQUEST_CODE)
        return
   }

    var task : Task <Location> = fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation
    task.addOnSuccessListener(object : OnSuccessListener<Location> {
        override fun onSuccess(location: Location?) {

         if(location !=null){
             currentLocation =location
             Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Lati: "+currentLocation.latitude.toString() + "  Long: " +
                     currentLocation.longitude.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
             val supportMapFragment = (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment?)!!
             supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this@MapsActivity)

         }
        }

    })






}

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap
    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    val latLng = LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude)
    val markerOptions = MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("I am here")
    googleMap?.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng))
    googleMap?.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 5f))
    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions)
}


override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String?>,
                                        grantResults: IntArray) {
   if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE){
    if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] ==
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        fetchLastLocation()
    }
   }
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142089/how-to-display-my-location-on-google-maps-for-android-api-v2

Comment: what about that that lateinit currentLocation

Comment: You may also want to take a look at this documentation on how select [current place of a device](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/current-place-tutorial)